# ¿como eliminar varios registros con un dato en común en laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Tengo una colección de datos y quiero borrar los que tengan un dato en común, por ejemplo la fecha de creación, y que todos los que tengan esa misma fecha se eliminen.
este es mi código:

```
  public function destroy($id)
    {

      $registros=NominaEstatalModel::where('qna_ini',"resgistroencomun")->get()->toArray();
      $eliminados = NominaEstatalModel::destroy($registros);
     return redirect('/nomina_estatal');

}
```

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agrega el código como texto (no como imagen) a la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

```
Model:where('created_at', $date)->delete();
```

**por ejemplo para Users sería...**

```
Users:where('created_at', $date)->delete();
```

Comment: Es necesaria una explicación sobre lo que hace el código y por qué soluciona el problema, no es solo escribir el código. Por favor haz el tour y conoce cómo funciona StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

El chiste más conocido por cualquier informático que tenga tiempo ejerciendo la profesión: Cuando haces un *"DELETE FROM table..."* pero se te olvidó el **WHERE**.

En Laravel sucede exactamente igual. Solo debes escoger una condición en común que satisfaga tu caso y borrar los elementos requeridos. Incluso la [documentación trae un ejemplo bastante claro.](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#delete-statements) A fin de cuentas, solo debes apoyarte en las funcionalidades de las query builder para construir tu consulta en eloquent y poder borrar lo que necesitas, como el ejemplo a continuación;

```
DB::table('users')->where('votes', '>', 100)->delete();

//O usando Models de Laravel

User::where('votes', '>', 100)->delete();
```